# Why this If statment executing even when the condition is false?

Tags: c, macros

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()    
{    
    // We use a trick involving exclusive-or to swap two variables
    #define SWAP(a, b)  a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; 

    int x = 10;
    int y = 5;
    printf("%d%d\n",x,y );

    if(x < 0)
        SWAP(x, y);

    printf("%d%d",x,y );

    return 0;     
}
```

The output is:

```
105
515
```

From where this 5 15 is coming even though condition is evaluating to false in if (10 <0 is false)?

Comment: Discovering the XOR swap is a bit like discovering that you can steer your car with your knees. Try it once, forget it, and move on.

Answer (score 9):

Your SWAP macro call is replaced by the preprocessor. Although it appears on one line, only the first statement is part of the `if` statement.

```
if(x < 0)
    SWAP(x, y);
```

Is transformed by the pre-processor to:

```
if(x < 0)
    a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; ;
```

Which is effectively the same as:

```
if(x < 0)
    a ^= b; 
b ^= a; 
a ^= b;
;
```

You could solve this by putting all the statements in the macro definition into a block, like this:

```
#define SWAP(a, b)  do { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; } while( 0 )
```

The do/while trick allows you to follow the SWAP call with a semicolon.

Comment: Additionally, the macro parameter names should be enclosed in parentheses where they appear in the replacement list.

Comment: When you made the substitution what happened to ; which was there after SWAP in main? did you ignore it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Good point; that's good style in general. user2799508 - That semicolon is still in the code, as an empty statement. I've added it in the sample code above.

Answer (score 2):

Because the macro body isn't a statement: it's three.

If you substitute the macro for its definition, the `if` reads like:

```
if(x < 0)
  x ^= y; x ^= y; x ^= y;
```

which of course is the same as:

```
if(x < 0)
  x ^= y;
x ^= y;
x ^= y;
```

Since there are no braces around the macro call, only the first assignment "belongs" to the `if`.

The fix is to enclose the macro in a "dummy" loop:

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; } while(0)
```

Note that the macro definition does *not* end with a semicolon.

Comment: Did you forgot a } above?

Answer (score 1):

`#define` statements behave as macro substitutions of text being done by the pre-processor. Your `if` statement is actually converted to this (before being compiled):

```
if(x < 0)
    x ^= y; x ^= y; x ^= y;;
```

Notice how you don't have any curly braces and there is more than one expression inside the if. Only the first one is not being executed.

Every compiler should support a flag to output only the preprocessed code. In case of gcc, you can see it with this: `gcc -E -P i.c` in case you're in doubt.

Comment: In your substitution of text why are you ignoring the original semicolon SWAP (in main ) had?

Comment: This is dangerous, use rather Andy Thomas' method.

Comment: If I put the MACRO in {} , I am getting compilation error as the ; is creating trouble. so why this ; was ignored in your substitution ?

Comment: @user2799508 What substitution are you referring to? My second code where I remove the trailing `;`? It ain't needed because that will turn your code into this: `x ^= y; x ^= y; x ^= y;;`

Comment: But in the first code block you have written x ^= y; x ^= y; x ^= y;

Comment: @user2799508 I just forgot the trailing `;` sorry, almost everyone forgot that too :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SWAP` macro is expanded into three statements: only one of them applies to the `if` statement. You could fix that by putting braces in the macro or, better still, using a dummy `loop` structure.

**But note**; if you *really* want to use XOR swap then you need to check that the addresses of the objects are not the same. Else you get a curious zeroing effect.

Putting it all together, you get this

```
#define SWAP(a, b)  do { if (&a != &b){ a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; } } while 0
```

which solves both issues. The `do` `while` loop means the user of `SWAP` has to terminate with a `;`: this is good practice when building macros.